# GDPR Extention and PETITIONs (in Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, gdpr, privacy, petition

(CiviCRM on Wordpress) We see that in Petitions it is not possible to activate the GDPR Extention for Privacy Policy Acceptance. How is it possible? Are we wrong?

The Privacy Policy Acceptance following a Petition signature does not seem prohibited by the GDPR.

Do we get the same result with a work-arround?

Answer (score 1):

We resolve by using CiviRules: "if the action is a petition signing then accept the Privacy Policy and Communication Preferences for that contact".